# Need help with joining animation from several rigs to one (same mesh and bones on each rig)

Tags: animation, bones

I have several rigs with animations. All are the copies with same 5 bones and mesh (no defined armature, just bones).
Mostly the same first and last frame, enabling easy transitions between animations.
Conditions have changed and now I need to put all animations into one rig and export it to be imported into a game engine.

The problem is that I've transformed locations somewhere along the line on some rigs so the point of origin has moved to world origin. So when I copy location and rotation keyframes from one rig to the target rig, sometimes that gives unwanted movement in location and rotation.

I've tried to solve it by delta transforms to zero out movement both for location and the animations.
Also tried to make actions of it and put it into nonlinear animations before that.

Is there some addon that can help to solve this and sanitize the animations or is my only option to remake all animation in the target rig? (It's about 28 different animations so I rather avoid it)
Saw another thread about Copy Global Transform. Can this work?

Comment: Hello, what you could do is move the bones with the help of the Graph Editor so that they align with the other actions?

Comment: Thanks, that is a good tip I can try